# String search using regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, quotation-marks

i am trying to match strings that dont contain quotation marks but **they can contain escaped quotation marks**.

when i say string i mean quotation marks and a string inside them.

i am using this regular expression but it does not work.

```
\"(?![^\\\\]\")\"
```

**solution:**

```
@"""[^""\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^""\\\r\n]*)*"""
```

the code (c#)

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input,@"""[^""\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^""\\\r\n]*)*""");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            result += match.Index + " " + match.Value + System.Environment.NewLine ;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html

Note that you'll need to escape certain chars properly (depending on what string literal you use)! The following demo:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string input = "foo \"some \\\" text\" bar";

    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"""[^""\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^""\\\r\n]*)*""");

    if (match.Success)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(input);
      Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
    }
  }
}
```

will print:

```
foo "some \" text" bar
"some \" text"
```

Comment: @jaywayco, Post non matched examples

Comment: it should match this blah\"blah and not this blah"blah

Comment: @polishchuk, I took the liberty to add an example based on the (working!) regex.

Comment: @jaywayco, Check, it will match `"blah\"blah"` and `"blah"` from `"blah"blah"`, if you wanna to validate string input, just put `^` at start and `$` at end, e.g.: `^"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"$`, so it will match `"blah\"blah"`, but not `"blah"blah"`.

Comment: for it to work in c# it need to be     \"[^\"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^\"\\\r\n]*)*\"

Comment: @yossi, it depends on the string literal you choose. You only need to escape the `"` by adding another `"` in front of it when using the `@"..."` literal, as can be seen by running the demo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*
```